# Each new row should create an independent word document with the same format

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I have the following code that fills in a word document template. 
What I want to do is to create a new document for each row as I fill in the worksheet.

I tried changing the bookmark's `Range` by adding

```
Range("e5").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
loop
```

But the whole thing crashed...

```
Sub CreateWR()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim objword As Object
    Set objword = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objword.Visible = True

    objword.Documents.Open ("C:\User\Documents\FileControl\template.doc")
    With objword.ActiveDocument
    .Bookmarks("PropertyName").Range.Text = ws.Range("a2").Value
    .Bookmarks("ProjectNumber").Range.Text = ws.Range("b2").Value
    .Bookmarks("BudgetNumber").Range.Text = ws.Range("c2").Value
    .Bookmarks("ProjecName").Range.Text = ws.Range("d2").Value
    .Bookmarks("Vendor_1").Range.Text = ws.Range("e2").Value
    .Bookmarks("Price_1").Range.Text = ws.Range("f2").Value
    .Bookmarks("Vendor_2").Range.Text = ws.Range("g2").Value
    .Bookmarks("Price_2").Range.Text = ws.Range("h2").Value
    .Bookmarks("Vendor_3").Range.Text = ws.Range("i2").Value
    .Bookmarks("Price_3").Range.Text = ws.Range("j2").Value
    .Bookmarks("Vendor_1_2").Range.Text = ws.Range("e2").Value
    .Bookmarks("RequestedBy").Range.Text = ws.Range("m2").Value

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What error do you get? Do you have the file on your disk or you just trying to create it?

Comment: I didn't even get an error, excel just crashed every time I ran the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not your final solution, as it's not 100% clear what the upper value should be for the row counter, but to give you a start, see below.

The `For` loops the number of rows. For the moment, I've put `5` there, for you to test whether the basics work.

The document is generated inside this loop. Note that `Open` has been changed to `Add` in order to create a *new* document from the template. Also, the object variable `objDoc` is declared at the top and the new document assigned to it. This is also used to address the bookmarks, rather than `ActiveDocument`. At the end of the loop `objDoc` is set to `Nothing` in preparation for the next iteration.

The `rowCounter` has been substituted for the static row values in the original code, so each loop will move to the next row.

```
Sub CreateWR()        
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rowCounter as Long
    Dim objword As Object
    Dim objDoc as Object
    Set objword = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objword.Visible = True

    For rowCounter = 2 to 5
      Set objDoc = objword.Documents.Add ("C:\User\Documents\FileControl\template.doc")
      With objDoc
        .Bookmarks("PropertyName").Range.Text = ws.Range("a" & CStr(rowCounter)).Value
        .Bookmarks("ProjectNumber").Range.Text = ws.Range("b" & CStr(rowCounter)).Value
        .Bookmarks("BudgetNumber").Range.Text = ws.Range("c" & CStr(rowCounter)).Value
        .Bookmarks("ProjecName").Range.Text = ws.Range("d" & CStr(rowCounter)).Value
        .Bookmarks("Vendor_1").Range.Text = ws.Range("e" & CStr(rowCounter)).Value
        .Bookmarks("Price_1").Range.Text = ws.Range("f" & CStr(rowCounter)).Value
        .Bookmarks("Vendor_2").Range.Text = ws.Range("g" & CStr(rowCounter)).Value
        .Bookmarks("Price_2").Range.Text = ws.Range("h" & CStr(rowCounter)).Value
        .Bookmarks("Vendor_3").Range.Text = ws.Range("i" & CStr(rowCounter)).Value
        .Bookmarks("Price_3").Range.Text = ws.Range("j" & CStr(rowCounter)).Value
        .Bookmarks("Vendor_1_2").Range.Text = ws.Range("e" & CStr(rowCounter)).Value
        .Bookmarks("RequestedBy").Range.Text = ws.Range("m" & CStr(rowCounter)).Value
      End With
      Set objDoc = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for all the helpful tips! I didn' want to go into so much detail, I felt that I would be asking you to do my job, so I just asked the major obstacle, by the way i solved the row counter by using the CurRow feature. I m not allowed to vote yet(or at least they don't count mine as a vote), but thanks to you I finished the project before the expected date

Comment: Great :-)! Glad I could help. You did a good job on the basics for asking, so streamlining the code a bit and explaining that was no problem.